# How to convert date from one format to another?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm having the date in this format in a Excel worksheet 03-Dec-10. So its not compatible while inserting it into the database. How to convert the date to the acceptable format?

Comment: How does it get from the Excel document to PHP? How are you inserting into the database? Care to provide any details at all?

Comment: Yes friends...From Excel it comes as 03-Dec-10 and inserted to database as string

Comment: @Rajasekar: You're still providing zero detail. Does the date spontaneously become sentient and magic itself into the database?

Comment: im just inserting all the columns into the database by imploding each rows and inserting seperate cells to seperate field

Comment: @Rajasekar: Then do so. Explain in detail the steps that you take in your attempt, with examples of code. It involves more than a single sentence of poorly formatted English. That would make a good question.

Comment: @Unknwntech the asker has 163 questions under his belt, he's not a total newbie any more. That he didn't add details was maybe due to a misunderstanding, but it's the right thing to ask for more details. The question *is* bad in its current form, and the fact that there are 4 answers is only due to the community's extremely developed ability to make educated guesses. Anyway, for anyone interested in answering, more detail can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505218/how-to-compare-two-dates-from-database-which-gets-records-from-excel) now

Comment: @Pekka: Precisely. @Unkwntech: I don't mean to be an ass here, but fully developed questions are good for everybody. This isn't a message board. Also I'm afraid you misspelt my name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Jon's answer is correct, here is another option:

```
$input = '03-Dec-10';
$date = date('Ymd', strtotime($input));
```

Comment: Can we I convert in reverse... like 2010-12-3 to 03-Dec-10 ?...plz help mate

Comment: This is a fine solution. Why was this question asked a second time? What about this answer is not satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = '03-Dec-10';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y', $input);
echo $date->format('Ymd'); // or possibly 'Y-m-d'
```

This will output `20101203`, which is presumably what you want. If it's not exactly what you are after, have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

You can also do the reverse:

```
$input = '20101203';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $input);
echo $date->format('d-M-y');
```

Comment: MySQL generally likes dates in Y-m-d format for insertion, although Ymd may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from Excel itself, you can put this formula into another column

```
=TEXT(A2, "YYYYmmdd")
```

Then copy down.  This produces a compatible 8-digit date.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach, you can always dump your current format to a string, like how you have it, and use string operations to substring and reorganize.  I know for a fact that MySQL accepts string values for `DATETIME` fields.

```
$day = substr($input, 0, 2);
$month = substr($input, 2, 3);
switch($month){
    case "Jan":
        $month = "01";
        break;
    ...
}
```